# Can access AppEngine SDK sites via local ip-address when localhost works just fine and a MacOSX

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook, macos

Can access AppEngine SDK sites via local ip-address when localhost works just fine and a MacOSX using the GoogleAppEngineLauncher.

I'm trying to setup facebook development site (using a dyndns.org hostname pointing at my firewall which redirects the call to my mac book).

It seems like GoogleAppEngineLauncher defaults to localhost and blocks access to the ip-address directly. 
Is there a way to change that behaviour in GoogleAppEngineLauncher?
Is this some kind of limitation built in by Google?

It doesn't seem to be an issue of configuration, because there isn't any settings for this.
So I'm guessing patching the source will be required?

Answer (score 9):

As per the latest [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?csw=1#Python_Command-line_arguments) `-a` wont work anymore.

This is possible by passing `--host` argument with `dev_appserver.py` command

`dev_appserver --host=<your_ip_address> <your_app>`

`--host=
    The host address to use for the server. You may need to set this to be able to access the development server from another computer on your network. An address of 0.0.0.0 allows both localhost access and hostname access. Default is localhost.`

if you want to access development server using  localhost & ip address, use this command:

`dev_appserver.py --host=0.0.0.0 <your_app>`

Answer (score 5):

For the eclipse (PyDev) users, Right-click on your project **`Run As > Run Configurations...`**

In the **Arguments Tab**, add the -a and -p arguments:

```
-a 0.0.0.0 -p 80 "${workspace_loc:project}"
```

Comment: -a 0.0.0.0 helps you by not hard coding your machine' current IP address

Answer (score 4):

This is possible by passing the `-a` argument to `dev_appserver.py`, i.e. `dev_appserver.py -a <your-ip> <your_app>`. See also [this article on using public IP addresses with the Google App Engine SDK](http://www.ventanazul.com/webzine/articles/public-ip-google-app-engine-development-server).

Comment: May not be able to do this from AppEngineLauncher, but I think it is the right answer?

Comment: You can do it from the launcher, in the settings page.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?csw=1#Python_Command-line_arguments), you can now do this by opening application settings (double-click app in the GoogleAppEngineLauncher), and adding a flag `--host=0.0.0.0`  It doesn't look like the `-a` flag works anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Per the docs, it's technically possible:

> --address=...
>
> The host address to use for the
>   server. You may need to set this to be
>   able to access the development server
>   from another computer on your network.
>   An address of 0.0.0.0 allows both
>   localhost access and hostname access.
>   Default is localhost.

However, it may be risky: `dev_appserver` is strictly focused on *development*, not hardened in terms of security against the attacks you might be subject to if you serve on the open net.  To deploy App Engine apps on your own server(s) (or Amazon, etc), you might be better off with alternative, open-source third-party solutions like [appscale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/) or [typhoonae](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/)!

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio with Google App Engine plugin.
Just add `httpAddress = '0.0.0.0'` to app cfg in build.grade file.