# Is there any way to access GAE dev app server in the local network?

Tags: google-app-engine, local-network

If I access my web site via http://localhost:8080 from the same Win 7 PC, where server is running, then it works well.

If I try to access that from another PC (with usage of my internal PC's ip http://192.168.1.98:8080), then it doesn't work. Moreover, it is not accessible with this ip even on the same machine. What am I doing wrong?

(I've tried to disable firewall on my Win 7 PC - it didn't help)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can access AppEngine SDK sites via local ip-address when localhost works just fine and a MacOSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168409/can-access-appengine-sdk-sites-via-local-ip-address-when-localhost-works-just-fin)

Comment: Having changed to 0.0.0.0, what do I set `LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL` to? in android I mean

Answer (score 88, accepted):

First check whether your server listens on loopback or on all interfaces - in command line type in `netstat -an` find a line with port 8080 and state LISTENING, something like this:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

If IP is 0.0.0.0 it means it listens on all IP addresses and the problem is with something else blocking it.

If IP is 127.0.0.1 then you need to bind to 0.0.0.0 address. And now the fun beings - according to [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html), you should add `--address=0.0.0.0` or `--host=0.0.0.0` to arguments in run configuration (depends on GAE version - thank you @momijigari). But in my case I have also GWT and parameters go to GWT and it does not accept this argument. But on the other hand listens on all interfaces, which I personally was trying to change to localhost. The GWT has `-bindAddress` parameter though, but it sets only address for code server (one with 9997 port by default), not HTTP.

Comment: Thanks, usage of `--address=0.0.0.0` helped.

Comment: Note that newer versions of app engine dev server use --host instead of --address

Comment: i get an error when trying this "dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --address=0.0.0.0
2014-01-17 20:42:57 (Process exited with code 2)"

Comment: Ok I found a solution, Will write below

Comment: I'm on gae version 1.8.9 and `--address=0.0.0.0` did the trick

Comment: For the new Google App Engine SDK (version 1.9.20) `--host=0.0.0.0` is the correct argument

Comment: The latest version as of now (1.9.30) seem to work with `--address=0.0.0.0`

Comment: If your using in android studio / Intellij , go to edit configurations then in address put 0.0.0.0 , you may need to uncheck sync with gradle file. It works for me , thanks :)

Comment: great! this solves my issue. I am trying to use Docker to run the Gcloud dev server and add this option to the command.

Comment: `--host=0.0.0.0` "worked" for me, but then I get "Request host is not whitelist enabled for this server. Please use the --host command-line flag to whitelist a specific host (recommended) or use --enable_host_checking to disable host checking. See the command-line flags help text for more information." So I fixed it by specifying my current local ip address instead: `--host=192.168.8.166`

Comment: If you're using gradle to run the server, it's also `host`: `host = "0.0.0.0"` inside the `run` struct.

Answer (score 20):

## Command line

Pass this program argument:

```
--address=0.0.0.0
```

## Eclipse

Start your dev server with this extra program argument (you can find this under “debug configurations” in eclipse):

```
--address=0.0.0.0
```

## Gradle

If you’re using  appengine-gradle-plugin +2.0.0, then you need to set it like this:

```
appengine {
    host = "0.0.0.0"
    port = 8888
    ...
```

If you're using appengine gradle plugin before version 2.0.0, then you need to set it like this:

```
appengine {
    httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    httpPort = 8888
    ...
```

## Maven

```
<configuration> 
    <address>0.0.0.0</address>
    ...
```

Comment: In 2.4.3 version of gradle plugin config is `appengine { run { host = "0.0.0.0" } }`

Answer (score 18):

Little update. Since version 1.8.7 you have to set a param "--host" instead of "--address"

So just add **--host=0.0.0.0**

Comment: At version 1.8.9 the [Command-Line Arguments](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments) doc says "--address".

Comment: Works for me on 1.9.6

Answer (score 5):

I got it working using the suggestions above for --host=0.0.0.0.
Here are the steps.

1. While on the project go to Edit > Application Settings
2. Add to Extra Command Line Flags

[image: Google App Engine Settings]

[image: Added Extra Command Line Flags]

Comment: Hey, thanks, this helped me when I set up the GAE Launcher on a notebook back in March (version 1.9.34)! However, when I try to do the same on a new notebook, with version 1.9.38, clicking Update does _nothing_. If anyone can confirm it still works on newer versions and that I'm not doing something dumb, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running devserver through maven add

```
<address>0.0.0.0</address>
```

under your

```
<configuration>
```

section in your appengine-maven-plugin.

Comment: Wish I had seen this earlier. Check out [all options here](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/source/browse/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/devappserver/AbstractDevAppServerMojo.java?name=master).

Answer (score 3):

For Google App Engine 1.8.9 (Java only), adding **-a 0.0.0.0** for all interfaces, worked for me.

```
-a 0.0.0.0 --port=8888 "/home/dude/workspace-java/me.dude.thermo-AppEngine/war"
```

Comment: This renders: `dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -a`

Comment: My answer was for Java only. Answer updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Gradle build file:

```
appengine {
    httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
}
```

([Gradle App Engine plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin))

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse users can do the following in the GUI to implement the [Command-Line Arguments](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments):

Right click on project name -> Debug As (or Run As) -> Configurations... -> Arguments

In the Program arguments area replace

```
--port=8888
```

with

```
--port=8888 --host=0.0.0.0
```

or

```
--port=8888 --address=0.0.0.0
```

depending on the AppEngine SDK version, then also check port availability and software firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Eclipse.

I've tryied to add `--address=0.0.0.0`, but it didn't work for me.

Then I've removed `--port=8888` entity from the command line arguments => server runs on default port 8080 and only then team members could connect to my machine via my IP address.

Finally, try to remove port entity and add `--address=0.0.0.0` entity as it was described in early posts

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Get the LAN IP

Goto your Windows Command Console (Press Win+R, then type "cmd"). In the console, enter "ipconfig". You will see a list of display. Under Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi, get the IPv4 Address. It will be something 192.168.x.x

LAN IP : 192.168.x.x

Step 2:

Go to Eclipse, Open the Configured server

[image: GAE Development server config]

Under Properties of GAE Development Server -> Local Interface address to bind to, enter the LAN IP address, and save.

Step 3:

Now you can access the GAE server by

http://192.168.x.x:8888/

8888 - Refers to the Port Number, as mentioned in the GAE  development server

Answer (score 0):

-bindAddress 0.0.0.0

is what i needed. I added it just before the -port arg.  This was via Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

To access the GAE development server(Local Sever) withing LAN from any machine(PC/Mobile), you need to configure the app engine to accept request from any ip as follows;

Run Configuration -> Arguments -> Program Arguments

**--address=0.0.0.0 port=8181**

**Note**: You can use any available port.

[image]

Once this done, you can just access this local server by entering the PC's IP address and above configured port;

http://192.168.1.102:8181/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If using GWT, add this program arguments

```
-bindAddress 0.0.0.0
```