# Howto connect to localhost:8888 from another device on the same network?

Tags: google-app-engine, networking

I'm trying to test my application that I develop using the Google AppEngine.

When I want to test from the computer I use to develop the application ("localhost:8888" in my browser) everything works perfectly.

But when I want to test it from my android device's browser, using "192.168.5.194:8888" (the local IP adrress of the computer), it gives me nothing (it just tries to connect to the site unsuccesfully).

So, my computer and my browser are on the same LAN. The comp is running a win7. I use eclipse (Kepler) to develop.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534967/is-there-any-way-to-access-gae-dev-app-server-in-the-local-network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver) under command line arguments there is a parameter called host.

You can start you local environment like
`./dev_appserver --host=0.0.0.0`

You have to replace 0 with your actual network ip address, something like `192.168.0.42` which can be found with `ifconfig` command in a linux all mac terminal, `ipconfig` for windows.

If you visit from your favorite browser your actual ip address for example `192.168.0.42:8080` at 8080 port if you didn't set one manually you will be able to access your local machine from any browser on the network.

The above instructions apply only in a non graphical environment if you are using the application for starting your server I haven't checked it out, and I can't right now cause I am running on Linux, but I am quite confident that you can define a host somewhere in the parameters.

Comment: Damn, didn't see the duplicate

Comment: and it should be ipconfig for windows :-P :-)

Answer (score 3):

Add the following command line flag to the App Engine launcher: `--host=0.0.0.0`

Comment: I'm sry, I didn't mention it was a Java server.
Thanks to voscausa, I found out it should be It should be --address=0.0.0.0 (or --address=<local ip address>).