# App engine dev server through LAN. Cloud storage bug

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, lan, devserver

To access the dev server through LAN, we set the --host to 0.0.0.0 as mentioned i the post [Is there any way to access GAE dev app server in the local network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534967/is-there-any-way-to-access-gae-dev-app-server-in-the-local-network). But if i upload a file with this settings, I am not able to access the image (through image serving url by blob_key) as it is uploaded to 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1 (local host). Can anyone suggest a solution for it?