# Making web server with Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, local-network

I created the app.yaml and index.py files in a folder.

app.yaml

```
application: firstpython
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.py
```

index.py

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, World'
```

When I run the `dev_appserver.py folder` command, I see the page from my own computer by typing localhost:8080. But computers on the same network another can not reach this page by typing my ip, eg 192.168.1.35:8080.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to make it completely public or do a local demo?

Comment: I want to local demo.    "dev_appserver.py --host 192.168.1.36 --port 8081 ./out/app_engine/"  works... Thank you...

Comment: not about appengine. issue is correctly configuring your network.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to access GAE dev app server in the local network?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534967/is-there-any-way-to-access-gae-dev-app-server-in-the-local-network)