# Why I cannot reach Google Cloud Dev App Server on VM (port 8080)

Tags: google-app-engine, port, firewall

I have up and running Google App Engine instance on production and it's working fine.
I wanted to create development environment for coding and testing because needed softwares (ex. SDK) cannot be install locally on my computer.
So I create to Google Cloud a Virtual Machine (VM, Debian 10) and checked in my code from App Engine to VM.

Dev App Server seems to work ok.
Dev App Server log shows that it's working
[image: Dev App Server log shows that it's working]

I can start Dev App Server (using port 8080) on VM but when I try to reached it, browser says "This site can’t be reached".
I use VM's external IP address (it's ephemeral, which means that it's not static ip address).

Firewall rules should be ok.(port 8080). Below is some of the rules.

Firewall setup:
[image: Firewall setup]

I installed apache2 on the VM and tried to reached index page (port 80) -> works fine!

My question is:
Why I cannot reach my dev app server which is using port 8080?
Is it because of port rules?
Something else, what?

Comment: I think that I got a solution. My app dev server is listening only localhost, so I have to change it to have an access from internet.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server#command-line-arguments

Answer (score 1):

It says, that instance is running on `localhost:8080`. So maybe app is configured to listen not on `0.0.0.0:8080` but on `localhost:8080`.

In this case it could not be reached from any other network except localhost even if firewall allows access to it.

Use `netstat -an` to find out if there is `0.0.0.0:8080`

You could also use telnet to test if port is open:

```
telnet someIP somePort
```

If not:

> The development server command supports the following command-line
> arguments:
>
> ```
> --address=...
> ```
>
> The host address to use for the server. You might need to set this to
> be able to access the development server from another computer on your
> network. An address of `0.0.0.0` allows both localhost access and
> hostname access. Default: `localhost`.

[Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server?csw=1)

[Similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534967/is-there-any-way-to-access-gae-dev-app-server-in-the-local-network)

If you use maven, then you could modify your **pom.xml** file the next way:

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
     <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.0</version>
     <configuration>
       <devserver.host>0.0.0.0</devserver.host>
       <devserver.port>8080</devserver.port>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-maven) and try to launch your project as usual

Comment: Yep, you are right. Dev App Server is connected only localhost. 
Next question is that where I can setup so that it allows connection from internet.

Comment: @InkwonHwang Have you opened **Similar thread** link and read about usage examples? It depends on what you use.

Comment: Thanks @Gryu for replying! 
Basically I need to know where I can put command line arguments --address=0.0.0.0
Normally arguments are used while using script ex. sh file. I'm using command 
mvn appengine:devserver

Should is do?

mvn appengine:devserver --address=0.0.0.0