# Can't reach local GAE server through my ip

Tags: google-app-engine, localhost, gae-eclipse-plugin

I developing an app with GAE as a back-end, when I run GAE server locally I can reach it in the browser through `localhost:8888` but when I try to reach from an external device on the same wifi network, with my `<my local ip>:8888` I get no response. I was always using this way do debug my apps and back-ends and suddenly it stopped working?

Comment: You should reconfigure your firewall settings to allow external requests on that port.

Comment: @barakmanos I've tried to turn the firewall off. and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer at last, add 0.0.0.0 address to the servers run arguments. As described here :
[Can access AppEngine SDK sites via local ip-address when localhost works just fine and a MacOSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168409/can-access-appengine-sdk-sites-via-local-ip-address-when-localhost-works-just-fin)

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Using_URL_Fetch